Unordered txt file contents: How to design in proper dictionary
I have txt file and it's contents are unordered like below sample.  I must select first row because it has train run exact time.
my txt file has couple of summary 1, 2 and so on. hence, keys are same but values are different so I need to have summary1 one dict and summary2 another dict and so on. for remaining summary
The train ran in 6 minutes 25 seconds
Parameters selected:

Fix Path Until: 6/9/2024
train End: 11/6/2024
Min. Float Days: 0
Options: True, False, Nav

Summary1:

Num of CLASS 1 NECESSARY found: 8
Num of Shorts found in the path: 1110
Num of Lengths found in the path: 1313

Summary2:

Num of CLASS 1 NECESSARY found: 10
Num of Shorts found in the path: 1114
Num of Lengths found in the path:4567

I used pd.read_table and try to convert txt to proper data frame but no luck.
summary1 = dict()
result = []
a= pd.read_table('F.txt',header=None, delimiter=None)[0].to_list()
if 'summary1:' in a:
for x in a:
    print(x)

Expectation is couple of dictionaries I'd like to convert from the txt file  
summary1: {'Num of CLASS 1 NECESSARY found': '8','Num of Shorts found in the path:': '1110','Num of Lengths found in the path': '1313'}

summary2: {'Num of CLASS 1 NECESSARY found': '10','Num of Shorts found in the path:': '1114','Num of Lengths found in the path': '4567'}


Please highlight whatever part of your question is the sample of the text file and click the {} button to preserve line feeds and white space. Please also share what you would like this data to look like after it's all loaded up in dictionaries, dataframes, etc. It's not clear how you are wanting to shape this data.

This is just gibberish. Be absolutely clear (based on sample data and the code you've used) about what output you're getting versus what you expect

Please fix the code indentation. And what's the point of with open('F.txt') as f:? Yuo never use the f variable.

read_table() can't parse free-form text like that. It's for tabular data. You will need to write a custom parser for this.

Thank you so much for replying @Barmar. Expectation is couple of dictionaries from this txt. I have updated my code.

Your code indentation is wrong. The body of if needs to be indented. What don't you understand about "you have to write code that parses the text"?

If you are looking for dicts, it will be better to use with open. Something like this (with comments):
# `dict` to populate
dicts = {}

# using `io.StringIO` for `open('file.txt')` to get a file-like object
with StringIO(txt) as f:
    
    # use a `Flag` to know when to start
    flag = False
    
    # loop through `f`
    for line in f:
        
        # skip empty lines
        if not line in ['\n', '\r\n']:
            
            # new dict entry
            if line.strip().startswith('Summary'):
                
                # use first elem of split as `key` in `dicts`
                key = line.split(':', 1)[0]

                # initialize nested dict
                dicts[key] = {}
                
                # set `flag` to `True` at first found 'Summary`
                if not flag:
                    flag = True
            elif flag:
                # update nested dict (`key`) with `key:value` pairs
                dicts[key].update([[x.strip() for x in line.split(':', 1)]])

Output:
{'Summary1': {'Num of CLASS 1 NECESSARY found': '8',
  'Num of Shorts found in the path': '1110',
  'Num of Lengths found in the path': '1313'},
 'Summary2': {'Num of CLASS 1 NECESSARY found': '10',
  'Num of Shorts found in the path': '1114',
  'Num of Lengths found in the path': '4567'}}

If you know in which line the first 'Summary' starts, you could lose the Flag and skip the first lines. E.g., with itertools.islice (cf. here):
dicts = {}

from itertools import islice

# first `n` lines to skip
n = 7

with StringIO(txt) as f:
    for line in islice(f, n, None):
        if not line in ['\n', '\r\n']:
            if line.strip().startswith('Summary'):
                key = line.split(':', 1)[0]
                dicts[key] = {}
            else:
                dicts[key].update([[x.strip() for x in line.split(':', 1)]])

# same output


Of course, you could do this with pandas as well:
Step 1:

Use pd.read_csv; names will set column labels, skipinitialspace=True will strip whitespace.

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), 
                 sep=':', 
                 header=None,
                 skipinitialspace=True,
                 names=['keys', 'values'])

Step 2

Add a new column (here with df.assign) and populate it with the values from df['keys'] if they start with 'Summary' and forward fill blanks: Series.where, Series.str.startswith, Series.ffill.
Now, use df.dropna on the subset ['values', 'main_keys']. I.e.:

NaNs in df['values'] will occur only on dict separator lines (like 'Summary1:').
NaNs in df['main_keys'] will occur only in the 'Parameter' part.



df = (df.assign(main_keys =
                df['keys'].where(
                    df['keys'].str.startswith('Summary'))
                .ffill()
                )
      .dropna(subset=['values', 'main_keys'], ignore_index=True)
      )

We now have this output:
                               keys values main_keys
0    Num of CLASS 1 NECESSARY found      8  Summary1
1   Num of Shorts found in the path   1110  Summary1
2  Num of Lengths found in the path   1313  Summary1
3    Num of CLASS 1 NECESSARY found     10  Summary2
4   Num of Shorts found in the path   1114  Summary2
5  Num of Lengths found in the path   4567  Summary2

If this were your end goal, using pandas would make sense to me. But if you need the dicts, that requires yet another step:
Step 3:

Use df.groupby and groupby.apply with a custom lambda function (cf. this SO post):

dicts = (df.groupby('main_keys')[['keys', 'values']]
       .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['keys'],x['values'])))
       .to_dict())

# same output


Setup used
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """Parameters selected:

Fix Path Until: 6/9/2024
train End: 11/6/2024
Min. Float Days: 0
Options: True, False, Nav

Summary1:

Num of CLASS 1 NECESSARY found: 8
Num of Shorts found in the path: 1110
Num of Lengths found in the path: 1313

Summary2:

Num of CLASS 1 NECESSARY found: 10
Num of Shorts found in the path: 1114
Num of Lengths found in the path:4567"""


Lovely man. A evening dinner I own for you mate.

Sure @ouroboros1. will do so. will finish this
